# How to add custom menu upon right click on file / folder programmatically in c++ / QT?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, contextmenu

We have an app which syncs files and folder like the way dropbox does. This is an c++ / QT based installer.

We would like add custom menu in the right click context menu of a file or folder like the way dropbox does in the below screen shot.

We are targeting both windows & Mac platforms. Can anyone suggest me how to start with it?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

On Mac, you're going to have problems as adding to the general Finder Context Menu has been deprecated.

So, you may be thinking, if it's deprecated, then how do Dropbox do this? From what I've researched in the past, I believe they use code injection to inject into the running Finder application's address space and then an Objective-C feature known as method swizzling to change calling a method to one of their own, which is located in the injected code.

This is all fairly hardcore and very low level, but if you're going to go on that journey, you can start by looking into a library called mach_inject and googling about it. The source code can be found here: -

https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject

However, be aware that there are those that believe code-injection is wrong and won't install Dropbox or any other software that uses it. In addition, if you're planning on releasing a product in the Mac Store, I wouldn't expect any application that performs code injection to be allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any suggestions for windows as well?

Comment: If you google for "Windows add to context menu" it look like it's just a set of registry entries to be added.

Answer (score 1):

For windows, I could find a complete Shell extension example over here.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens?fid=519&select=3236397&fr=76&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=True&sort=Position&view=None&spc=Relaxed