# Add MAC OS/X Contextual Menu item in C

Tags: c, macos

I'm trying to add a Contextual Menu item to the right mouse click on Mac OS/X.  I have googled how to do this, but cannot find how I would program this in C, as opposed to using the GUI to add it.  If someone could just give me some pointers or a couple of buzz words I could google, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks....

-Chris

Comment: Which contextual menu? As the name implies, it's a different menu wherever you click.

Comment: Try keyword ["api" (along with "osx")](https://www.google.com/search?q=osx+api); add "mouse", "menu", "context", ...

Comment: Just trying to help... and this may not be `The Apple Way` but create one in the GUI and save it as `FUNKY` or something obvious, then have a look in ~/Library/Services

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516732/how-to-add-custom-menu-upon-right-click-on-file-folder-programmatically-in-c/16522573#16522573