# How do I add my own option to Finder's right click menu?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, contextmenu, finder

I have an app that basically takes a file path(s) and copies the data name and extension from it to be used in my app. I was wondering how to add on to the Finder right click menu (like Dropbox does) and do run some Objective-C code when clicked. (I need to get the path(s) of the selected file). Is there any way to do this? All the answers I've seen are very vague and unhelpful. I do not want to use mach_inject because my app might go onto the appstore, and I can probably get FinderSync API to work.

Comment: @moonman239 A little bit. The docs are either hard to understand or poorly written and I could find little code snippents I tried to implement but it was like "dead code"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add custom menu upon right click on file / folder programmatically in c++ / QT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516732/how-to-add-custom-menu-upon-right-click-on-file-folder-programmatically-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the FinderSync API in Yosemite; I'm fairly sure you don't need to sync anything, but you can use the API to install a toolbar and sidebar item as well.

Comment: I am actually coding it in xcode 4 (yes, my mac sux). Is there a way to get the api in xcode 4?

Comment: @Mark it would probably depend on your OS. IIRC 10.10 (yosemite) is the minimum version that includes these APIs